# Effective highpass filter with one opamp

Tags: filter

I have a phototransistor giving me some noise at about 100Hz and I am transmitting an IR signal at it of 10khz. I would like to completely eliminate the noise since it would be amplified at later stages and turned into discrete on, off signals using a comparator. I know about first order and second order high pass filters.

I currently have basic knowledge of analog electronics.

Is there any way to completely eliminate the 100 Hz signal?

Comment: *Completely* eliminating an existing signal band would not be the task for a single op-amp filter. However, a reasonably extreme attenuation of the 100 Hz signal is possible if you design the knee of your filter for as close to the desired pass frequency as possible, i.e. perhaps 8 KHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A easy quick solution would be to play around with FilterPro:

http://www.ti.com/tool/filterpro

You can use the wizard and just enter the needed parameters. Select a single stage and it will show you only single op-amp solutions. If you don't mind losing the DC offset you could just use a single high-pass.

Answer (score 0):

A notch filter sounds like something you may be looking for. Typically, using passive components (resistors and capacitors) you should be able to get +10dB attenuation at 100Hz. The "notch" filter goes in series with the signal path so it's fairly easy to implement. On the downside, a passive notch-filter may start to affect signals you want so consideration here should be taken.

A method that also goes parallel to the signal path is a simple series resonant circuit but this would probably be inappropriate in its basic configuration due to the values required for 100Hz attenuation.

Graphic equalizers use the 2nd method to "notch-out" a particular frequency and this uses the parallel method but "realizes" the high component values by using what are known as gyrator circuits. Please consider the concept of using a graphic equalizer and feedback your thoughts on how appropriate it may be - utilizing part of the circuit to achieve the attenuation required won't be too difficult.

The 1st method can be "fitted around" an op-amp to achieve a much steeper notch and it will also mean that signals you want at 10kHz will not be affected.

Here's a [decent article](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CHAQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.g3ynh.info%2Fcircuits%2FBob_Batey%2FLB-5.pdf&ei=3C5tUdyCC86c0wWJtoDAAw&usg=AFQjCNHX3lVCpQFdOAMG9MkuUstTDf4WSQ&sig2=QVgz9K7mp6aOePMSPkDDEQ&bvm=bv.45175338,d.d2k) on these types of filters